# How to solve error "Object library not registered" in VBA 2013?

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a macro in VBA Excel 2016, which extracts information from emails in Outlook (sender, subject, date, etc), and exports this information in an Excel sheet.

The code works fine in Excel 2016, however, in Office 2013 versions I get the following error:

> Automation error. Object library not registered

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me solve this error.

This error appears in the following line of the code:

```
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace ("MAPI")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA not Recognizing MAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248748/vba-not-recognizing-mapi)

Comment: -Possible +Definately

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I already solved the issue. It was so simply as, when defining the correct libraries for 2013 office, saving the file, closing it, and then opening it again and then running the macro.

But anyway, thanks guys!